# How does iBooks do this?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uiwebview, ios4, ibooks

I am currently displaying text in a uiwebview. However, I would like to allow a user to select text and perform some action with the selected text (google it). Apple has done this sort of thing with iBooks. When you click on a word you can choose to look up the word in a dictionary. How can I do the same thing with Webview?

UIMenuController seems to be what I need to look at. But I couldn't find any sample code on how to do this. I'm new to iPhone development please help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Starting in iOS 3.2 you can use [UIMenuController](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UIMenuController_Class/UIMenuController.html) to add additional [UIMenuItems](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIMenuItem_Class/Reference/MenuItem.html) to the system menu that appears when selecting text in a UIWebView. Here's a simple example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIMenuItem *defineItem = [[[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Define" action:@selector(defineSelection:)] autorelease];
    [[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] setMenuItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:defineItem]];
}

- (void)defineSelection:(id)sender {
    NSString *selection = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.getSelection().toString()"];
    // Do something with the selection
}
```

Apple describes how this works in the [Adding Custom Edit Menu Items](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/SystemIntegrationGuide_iPhoneOS/AddingCustomEditMenuItems/AddingCustomEditMenuItems.html) section of the Device Features Programming Guide.

Answer (score 1):

[This recent blog post](http://quatermain.tumblr.com/post/782018154/something-else-you-cant-do-on-the-ipad-unless) from a developer would seem to suggest that at least in the iPad iOS branch, some iBooks functionality is based on private APIs.