# How to add Pop up Button in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, popup

The deafult pop up is get opened when I long press the music play option in any url from `UIWebView`.
I Want to add one more button in the pop up..Is it possible to do it..

Like I want to add `FETCH` button.

And Can I make changes in the default pop up functioning which is `OPEN` and `COPY`. shown below

[image]

I come to know that by google -

First of all, you really can’t add additional menu items to the default ones of the standard contextual menu. But you can switch off the contextual menu using a certain CSS property. So the solution would be to switch off the default menu and implement your own from scratch. And to implement your own contextual menu, you have to first catch the tab-and-hold gesture, get the coordinates of the finger on the screen, translate these coordinates into the coordinate system of the web page and finally look for the HTML elements at this location.

Comment: Did my answer resolve this for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NEW ANSWER:

Looks like this is what we want, here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3198220/700471

OLD ANSWER:

Okay, after some research, here's the deal:

What you describe in your question seems accurate:

> First of all, you really can’t add additional menu items to the
>   default ones of the standard contextual menu. But you can switch off
>   the contextual menu using a certain CSS property. So the solution
>   would be to switch off the default menu and implement your own from
>   scratch. And to implement your own contextual menu, you have to first
>   catch the tab-and-hold gesture, get the coordinates of the finger on
>   the screen, translate these coordinates into the coordinate system of
>   the web page and finally look for the HTML elements at this location.

So you are planning on implementing your own popover controller with contextual menu--fine, I won't get into that at all, I will assume you know how to do that.

What your question seems to be is, how do you take a long-tap gesture in the UIWebView and transform it into the coordinates of the webpage to find the DOM element that was selected, and use that as a context from which to generate your popover menu.

What I found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9940987/getting-selected-elements-programatically-from-uiwebview), specifically [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10061763/700471) with this line of code:

```
NSString *js = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.elementFromPoint(%f, %f).innerHTML", touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y];
```

That looks like the JS you would need to figure out *what* element had just been long-pressed, and of course you would need to do some figure-figure to see if it was a link and execute your context menu from there, but that's not something I've looked into.

Some further thoughts:

Probably the easiest course would be to attach a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to your UIWebView (this can be done easily in a nib) and make sure that the "Sent Action" points to an appropriate IBAction on your ViewController.  (I suppose you could use the delegate outlet as well, but I have never needed to do that.)

In any case, you can use the [locationOfTouch:inView:](http://www.google.com/url?url=http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIGestureRecognizer/locationOfTouch:inView:&rct=j&q=UIGestureRecognizer%20locationOfTouch&usg=AFQjCNFMZYd7Sk7HsMdJagJNx1Pb5pxiNg&sa=X&ei=WduIUIn_Fsji2gWan4HoDQ&ved=0CDMQygQwAg) method of your gesture recognizer, and the view you will probably want to use will be the UIWebView's content view, which I believe you can get with something like `myWebView.scrollView.subviews[0]` (or the objectAtIndex: variation if you are not using the new array index subscripts).

Anyway, I think I have provided enough to answer your question.

---

EDIT:

Okay, so you are still having trouble with this, so I went and made a test project and got it to work.  One thing that is slightly annoying about this is that WebKit somehow adds a "buffer" area around objects in the DOM, meaning that if you touch slightly *next to* a link it will still highlight, but when you use the JS command `elementFromPoint` it doesn't do that, so you kinda have to touch more carefully to trigger the popup using this method.  But, it works.

I made a blank project with the "single view" template, and threw a `UIWebView` into the xib, pointed its `delegate` outlet to File's Owner.  Then I put a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` into the xib, attached to the UIWebView.  I set its `delegate` as File's Owner, and set its `selector` outlet to the `longPressDetected` IBAction in File's Owner.  I also unchecked "Canceled in View" in the recognizer's properties in Interface Builder.

Here is the code for the view controller.

Interface:

```
//
//  WVTViewController.h
//  WebViewTest
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface WVTViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet    UIWebView   *myWebView;
@property (nonatomic)                   BOOL        didFirstLoad;

- (IBAction)longPressDetected:(id)sender;

@end
```

Implementation:

```
//
//  WVTViewController.m
//  WebViewTest
//

#import "WVTViewController.h"

@interface WVTViewController ()

@end

@implementation WVTViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // Just load google.
    NSURL *theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:theURL];
    [self.myWebView loadRequest:request];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    if (!self.didFirstLoad) {
        // Disable the default contextual menu.
        [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.style.webkitTouchCallout='none';"];
    }
}

// Called by the gesture recognizer.
- (IBAction)longPressDetected:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {

        NSLog(@"Long press detected.");

        CGPoint webViewCoordinates = [sender locationInView:self.myWebView];
        NSLog(@"WebView coordinates are: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(webViewCoordinates));

        // Find the DOM element
        NSString *locatorString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.elementFromPoint(%f, %f).innerHTML", webViewCoordinates.x, webViewCoordinates.y];
        NSString *result = [self.myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: locatorString];
        NSLog(@"Element Found: %@", result);

    }

}

// Necessary or the gesture recognizer won't call the IBAction.
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}

@end
```

As I said, I tested the above code and it works fine.  You can of course change up your JS and use something other than `innerHTML`, such as `tagName` or `href` or whatever you like.  Multiple checks may be necessary for what you're trying to do, possibly with queued JS commands (which would be lame), unless you could JSON-stringify the DOM object, pass it back to the Objective-C, convert to native objects and perform your checks in that environment--but, I'm no JS pro and I'm not going to investigate that.

As a note, I was a bit surprised that the coordinates that worked for `elementFromPoint` were the touch coordinates within the UIWebView itself.  I had rigged up a whole block of code that iterated through `myWebView.scrollView.subviews` and found the content view, then called `locationOfTouch:inView:` on that view.  But I was getting funky behavior, so on a hunch I used the webview coordinates and it worked fine, even on a big webpage when I was scrolled off to the side and down.  I suspect that some kind of Apple-programmed behavior inside the webview may translate those coordinates.  Possibly the JS's coordinate system is altered based on the way the content view is moved around inside the scrollview--that makes the most sense to me.

Comment: ya matt...ths answer helped me alot..and one thing which is unanswered tht wht should be take in to the javascipt..the below answer helped me correctly

Answer (score 2):

The proper and accurate way to answer this question is below link

http://www.icab.de/blog/2010/07/11/customize-the-contextual-menu-of-uiwebview/

Comment: ya thanks but thts not working ..I don't know y ...but I made all the changes ..the default pop up gets blocked but pop up according to the code not showing particular pop up

Comment: I made a test project and got it to work.  ...It also uses a lot less code than what's in this link.  See my answer.

Comment: Sent.  Although, perhaps unwise to put your email address somewhere publicly...  But hey, if it works, accept my answer at least ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can fire the event with something like this:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
  if( navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked )
  {
    // Handle your URL click here (open the popup menu)
    // ...
    return NO;
  }
  return YES;
}
```

don't forget to delegate the UIWebView

Comment: This is not what the question poster was looking for, at all, actually.